# HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Tags: c#, .net, windows, com

I am building a GIS Application but whenever I run the code it's giving me this error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
>   Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {FBF5715D-A05D-11D4-A64C-0008C711C8C1} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Also, in the Project Properties the Option for Register For COM Interop is disabled.

Comment: I tried both of the solutions suggested below to no avail. Does anyone have another idea?

Answer (score 40):

This could also be an issue of building the code using a `64 bit` configuration. You can try to select `x86` as the build platform which can solve this issue. To do this right-click the solution and select `Configuration Manager` From there you can change the `Platform` of the project using the 32-bit .dll to `x86`

Comment: I had the same problem in reverse - I needed a 64 bit project, `Any CPU` and `x32` didn't work.

Comment: I couldn't believe changing from 'Any CPU' to 'x86' would make all the difference but it did!

Answer (score 17):

Just looking at the message it sounds like one or more of the components that you reference, or one or more of their dependencies is not registered properly.

If you know which component it is you can use regsvr32.exe to register it, just open a command prompt, go to the directory where the component is and type `regsvr32 filename.dll` (assuming it's a dll), if it works, try to run the code again otherwise come back here with the error.

If you don't know which component it is, try re-installing/repairing the GIS software (I assume you've installed some GIS software that includes the component you're trying to use).

Comment: I have an .exe (not .dll). From the Visual Studio Cmd prompt (where the .exe is located) I ran "MyProgram.exe /regsvr"