# Exporting datagridview to excel file failed

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I'm trying to export datagridview to excel file but  I keep getting this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with `CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` failed due to the following error:

> 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

This is my code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;
excel.Visible = true;
for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        ws.Cells[j, i] = dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value;
    }
}
```

I get the error on this line of my code :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

Now I have already added `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` version **14.0.0.0** and I have configured my build to x86 but I'm still getting this error! I'm not sure what am I doing wrong!

Comment: do you have this line in your using at the top of the class file `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` also make sure that you manually add the reference to the references node manually..

Comment: You are going to regret using excel automation in the long run. Instead use a third party library that  can write excel files.

Comment: Similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003719/hresult-0x80040154-regdb-e-classnotreg

Comment: @MethodMan i added that and it didnt work!

Comment: @Magnus i already have but i have no choice ! im a noobi and i need something easy to grasp and comprehend which this seems like the easiest way

Comment: what is your project setup to run as ..anyCPU, x86.., etc..? also see if not using `regsvr32.exe` helps solve the problem.. running the same code on my local machine works just fine

Comment: @MethodMan i had to set it as x86...but how can i check if im using regsvr32.exe or not??

Comment: there are command line help that you can use try `regsvr32 ?` from the command line and see what the options are.. in .net honestly you shouldn't have to do this..

Comment: @MethodMan i tried to check it with regsvr32 ? in command line and i got an error saying :
the module "?" failed to load. make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for more problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files. the specified module could not be found

Comment: what version of VS are you using..?

Comment: @MethodMan VS Ultimate 2013 with Update 2 32-Bit

Comment: @Magnus can you name me a few of the third party libraries which you know of?

Comment: I've used [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/.net/excel-component.aspx) (costs money, but very good). But you can also use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) or check this SO answer on a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp