# Azure web app issue: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException 80040154 Class not registered

Tags: c#, azure, quickbooks

I am successfully hosting my quickbooks webconnector soap app on a private server. We are attempting to move it to an Azure api app.

When we attempt to run it, we are getting the error:

```
Error message: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {22E885D7-FB0B-49E3-B905-CCA6BD526B52} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

From remembering this issue when we originally deployed and from [this intuit post](https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/1017707-error-80040154-class-not-registered-exception-from-hresult-0x80040154-regdb_e_classnotreg-in-requestprocessor-2), I recall we have to make sure that our project build has a target platform of x86. We have done that. And when we use [CorFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to validate it is set to require 32bit, we can confirm that from the CorFlags output.

[image]

In the Azure portal, we have the app settings set to 32 bit as well. 
What else could we be missing?

Comment: Not sure if this is your exact situation but it can be by design https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#access-to-out-of-process-com-servers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been mentioned elsewhere: You cannot register COM objects in an App Service (Web App, API App). You'd need to work with something else that allows this (e.g. web/worker roles, Virtual Machines).

Comment: So this is not related to 32 bit vs 64 bit issues as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003719/hresult-0x80040154-regdb-e-classnotreg, but rather that I need to register a particular DLL using regsvr32.exe, which is not possible on an Azure Web App?  The new portal term for web role is Cloud Service, correct? And my asp.net asmx web service will run on that?